# Як перекласти поняття "source code"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Завжди було *"вихідний код"* але доволі часто такий термін сприймається не дуже і є неоднозначним.

Ще складніша ситуація, коли англійською скорочують цей термін до *"sources"*. Російською можна сказати *"исходники"*. Українською, на жаль, поки не зустрічав нормальний вислів для цього.

Comment: Думаю, варто відредагувати питання і уточнити, за якими критеріями «найкраще». Інакше отримаємо багато відповідей, які будуть суб'єктивно «найкращими» для їхніх авторів.

Comment: Також варто подумати про те як перекласти `source tree`, наприклад, це може бути `дерево сирців`

Comment: Хоча я вважаю питання дуже корисним — по-моєму, воно сформульоване невдало. Виглядає як опитування про особисті (необґрунтовані) відчуття про щось. Якби Ви задали хоча б якісь критерії «краще»: вживаність, інтуїтивна зрозумілість, однозначність (відсутність сторонніх відтінків), морфологічні ознвки, довжина, милозвучність.

Comment: Чітких критерієв у мене, на жаль, немає. Хочеться щоб гарно звучало та було зрозуміло іншим. Тобто з наведеного вами переліку я б в першу чергу обрав "інтуїтивну зрозумілість" та "милозвучність".

Answer (score 21):

Можна використовувати термін "вихідний код", "програмний код", "текст програми" тощо. Зараз "sources" популярно скорочувати до варіанту "сирці". Так, наприклад, [робить](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.uk.html) проект GNU.

Comment: Все що завгодно, але будь ласка, тільки не "сирці"!

Comment: Мені подобається, дуже вірно відображає сенс - "ось наліпили ми сирців і поставили випікатись"

Comment: Може тодi  "сорси" замiсть "сирцi"?

Comment: Можливо. Хоча скоріше це через те, що "сирий продукт", а не за звучанням

Comment: "вихідний код" зовсім не те, де тут вихід?

Comment: [http://sum.in.ua/s/vykhidnyj](Одне з тлумачень слів) - те, з чого починається.

Comment: @Makhauser Дійсно, "Ті мрії були *вихідною* точкою всіх його думок ".

Comment: Для мене **програмний код** - найкращій варіант, що зрозумілий усім, навіть далеким від ІТ (щойно помітив, що українською теж - Інформаційні Технології). А скорочено буде - код. Код програми, код додатку, код скрипта і т.і.

Answer (score 15):

На мою думку, добрим перекладом є "початковий код". Адже source code - це набір інструкцій (команд), що були спочатку написані програмістом, і можуть бути прочитані людьми, а не комп'ютером.

Щодо source, то часто зустрічаю "джерело". Думаю, гарний варіант, оскільки мається на увазі джерело інформації, а дане словосполучення широко використовують в українській мові.

Comment: Так, і на вікіпедії зараз відповідна стаття так і називається:
https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4

Comment: Може, тоді sources - це "початкод" чи "початкоди". Що скажуть лінгвісти? Чи є таке словотворення досить корректним?

Comment: В оригіналі маємо словосполучення, то, можливо, й тут так залишити?

Comment: Як на мене, то sources = джерела.

Comment: `джерельний код` як варіант зі статті у вікі звучить дуже поетично :)

Answer (score 9):

Хороший аналіз варіантів перекладу і відповідність їх принципам створення якісної термінології можна прочитати в [Прикладі аналізу терміну Source code](https://uk.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%B2/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%97/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F#Source_code):

> На професійному жаргоні це поняття часто позначають словом «**сирці**», що
>   є дуже зручним, милозвучним терміном для усного спілкування. Проте,
>   потрапивши в письмові ресурси, цей термін набув іншої форми: «**сирцевий
>   код**», який цілком втратив як свою милозвучність, так і влучність.
>   Одразу виникає проблема: слово «сирцевий» фонетично дуже близьке до
>   «серцевий», що створює небажані паралелі, до того ж, відрізнити
>   «сирцевий» від «серцевий» на слух майже неможливо. Це суперечить як
>   пункту 1.2, так і 1.3 наших правил. З іншого боку «сирцевий код» на
>   відміну від більшості інших термінів є однозначним і від нього легко
>   утворюються похідні такі як «дерево сирців». Також слова «сирцевий» і
>   «серцевий» з настільки віддалених галузей, що важко уявити плутанину
>   із цим під час розмови програмістів.
>
> Інший варіант перекладу цього терміна — «**джерельний код**», видається
>   прийнятнішим до вживання у письмових ресурсах. Проте і він має певні
>   проблеми. Адже слово «джерельний» в українській мові спричиняє
>   характерну асоціацію із джерельною водою, що надає термінові
>   «джерельний код» зайвий семантичний відтінок, і, знову ж таки, менше
>   відповідає пункту 1.3.
>
> Значно більш відповідним видається означення «**вихідний код**». Хоча
>   слово «вихідний» має кілька значень, у цьому випадку асоціація виникає
>   лише із одним — [«від якого або з якого починається щось; характерний
>   для початку якоїсь дії, якогось процесу»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/). Термін «вихідний код»
>   програми значно менш суперечливий, ніж два попередні, але все ж має
>   один недолік: викликає враження кальки із російського «исходный код».
>
> [Орфографічний словник Українського мовно-інформаційного фонду](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) в
>   розділі «синонімія» до слова «вихідний» серед інших подає слова
>   «початковий» та «твірний». Хоча словосполучення «**твірний код**» — досить
>   милозвучне, воно не передає потрібного змісту (може здатися, що
>   мається на увазі код, який програма обробляє, щоб видати якийсь
>   результат). Тому, здавалося б, найбільш відповідним нашим правилам
>   виявився термін «**початковий код**». Він досить чітко окреслює потрібне
>   поняття, складається із українських слів («код» можна вважати таким),
>   не має проблем із фонетично близькими словами (як «сирцевий»), легко
>   запам’ятовується та може бути зрозумілим без додаткових пояснень.
>   Проте, і цей варіант — не без недоліків. Проблема у тому, що
>   словосполучення «початковий код» має занадто широке значення, і може
>   захопити також, наприклад, original code, що є цілком іншим
>   поняттям (наприклад, в перекладі ліцензії GPL).
>
> Тому нам доведеться повернутись таки до джерельного коду та, можливо,
>   вихідного коду. Як виявилося, ідеального варіанту в українській мові
>   немає. Проте, для запозичення з англійської все ж замало підстав —
>   українські відповідники цьому терміну все ж є.

Показовим є і [обговорення статті **Початковий код** у Wikipedia](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), де можна побачити голосування та обговорення альтернативних варіантів:

- [Програмний код](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_%E2%86%92_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)
- [Вихідний код](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_%E2%86%92_%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)
- [Джерельний код](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_%E2%86%92_%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)
- [Текст програми](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_%E2%86%92_%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)
- [Початковий програмний код](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_%E2%86%92_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Comment: Незрозуміло, в якому місці «вихідний» менш суперечливе, ніж «джерельний». У контексті компіляції «вихідний» стає самоантонімічним (будучи одночасно антонімом до «вхідний»), тоді як джерельна вода в цьому процесі, як правило, не використовується — натомість, існує абстрактне поняття «джерело». «Вихідний» скальковано з російської, «сирці» — запозичено з російського сленгу (де воно є адаптацією англ. source), «джерельний» скальковано з англ. «source», «твірний» — своє рідне, але надто далеке за змістом. «Текст програми» — буквалізм, але «вихідний код» без нього нежиттєздатний.

Answer (score 4):

На мій погляд, найточнішим перекладом є *програмний код*, оскільки *source code* використовують переважно в програмуванні.

Як варіант, *source code* можна також перекласти як *код першоджерела* (два іменника підряд потрібно з англійської мови перекладати з кінця). Проте в такому випадку втрачається прив'язка до сфери застосування, а саме до програмування. Оскільки прив'язка до сфери, на мій погляд, є більш важливою, ніж дослівний переклад, то *програмний код* є хорошим компромісом.

*Source tree* може бути перекладене як *дерево програмних кодів* або *дерево програмних файлів* (хоча мені більше подобається слово *репозиторій*), а *look into sources* - *подивись у програмних файлах* або навіть простіше - *подивись у коді*.

Answer (score 3):

Вихідний код — дослівний переклад, він найбільш поширенний.
Але варто відзначити, що значний вітсоток популярності саме цього варіанту обумовлена значною кількістю перекладенних документів і науково-технічної літератури з англійської мови, зрозуміти це можливо переглянувши результати пошуку в пошукових системах.

"Сирці" — це зазвичай машинний переклад, у науково-технічній літературі дуже рідко використовуеться, є калькою з англійської мови.

В Вікіпедії на даний час сторінка має назву "Початковий код".

У Google кількість результатів розділилися так:
Вихідний код — ~2 180 000
Початковий код — ~704 000
Програмний код — ~256 000

Особисто мені дивно що склалося так, адже "source" ніколи не перекладалось як "вихід".

Comment: Відповіді виду «пропоную варіант» або «мені здається» не виглядають слушними, якщо не підтверджені посиланнями на поважні джерела; і той факт, що інші відповіді на це запитання також є *поганими*, не є виправданням для того, щоб надавати *ще одну погану* відповідь :)

Comment: Я з вами згоден, "Мені здається" це, мабуть, найгірше що можна було написати. Краще вже посилатися на себе.

Comment: В цьому і полягає проблема. На StackExchange не прийнято посилатися на власний авторитет. У більшості випадків ми не знаємо, хто ховається за юзернеймом автора відповіді. Грубо кажучи, ви можете бути професором університету з купою публікацій, а можете бути просто тим, хто починає вивчати мову (і тому помилятися). Щоб уникнути неточностей, варто завжди вказувати, хто **окрім вас** вважає так само. Якщо ніхто, то це поганий знак. Особисто я такі відповіді мінусую.

Comment: Сподіваюсь так значно краще

Comment: Я вже бачив цю правку. А який метод пошуку? фраза «вихідн**ого** коду» там враховується, наприклад?

Comment: Цього я не знаю, це питання скоріше до представників Google та їх системи пошуту.

Comment: Помилкові дані з пошукових систем
Спробуйте ось так https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%22+-%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC+-%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE

Answer (score 2):

Мені найчастіше зустрічались варіанти `початковий код` та `вихідний код`. Багато варіантів зібрано на [Словотворі](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/source-code).

Answer (score 2):

Як програміст можу сказати:

1. Це поняття є терміном, тому нам потрібен **держстандарт**, який затвердить його загальноприйнятий переклад, дасть визначення українською мовою і т. д. Спроби його перекласти не як термін дадуть багато варіантів з різними відтинками смислу, що круто для поету, але непридатне для техніки.
2. Я би дав таке визначення: source code - це код програми, написаний програмістом - автором цієї програми, який крім власне інструкції містить метадані, коментарі і т. д. Тобто це поняття вужче за "текст програми", яке може означати будь-який текст програми, а не лише написаний автором. Приміром, ми можемо застосувати дизассемблер, що дасть нам текст програми, який в англомовний літературі називають "disassembly", у випадку декомпіляції в мову вищого рівня це буде називатися "decompilation" або "decompiled code", "decompiled source", але це не те ж саме, що "source code".
3. Тож як це перекласти? Див. п. 1. - потрібен держстандарт і термін. Це може бути "джерело", "джерельний код", "початковий код", "вихідний код" і т. д., але це не має бути "хто в ліс, хто по дрова", це має бути одне, чітко обране слово, для чіткого поняття. Поки держстандарту немає, по суті, кожен може перекладати, як йому подобається.

Comment: З пунктами №2 і №3 дуже згоден. Водночас я б сказав, що це _термін з програмування_, а не _науковий_ термін (програмування — галузь ремесла/промисловості, а не науки). І цей термін може прийти як згори (держстандарт змінить фактичний стан речей), так і знизу (держстандарт просто зафіксує де-факто найуживаніший варіант). Тому обговорення того, який варіант кращий, по-моєму, цілком має сенс (до введення держстандарту — тим більше).

Answer (score 1):

[В рамках Drupal](https://localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/uk/translate?project&status=2&release=all&search=source%20code&author&context=all&limit=50&sid=0) ми перекладаємо source code як

- Вихідний код
- Програмний код
- Код

В залежності від контекстів. Найчастіше це все ж **вихідний код**

Answer (score 1):

Можна перекласти як "Першокод".
https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/sors-kod

Answer (score 0):

Поняття `source code` пішло не просто з програмування, а з компільованих мов програмування, адже саме в них звичайному користувачу можна побачити результат роботи, а код в свою чергу є недоступним. Тому саме `код` програми і є `source code`. У свою чергу, в некомпільованих мовах програмування програма запускається інтерпретатором. Тобто бере `код` або `source code` і перетворює в собі зрозумілу структуру.

**ВИСНОВОК**

`source code` - `код`

Comment: Компілятор перетворює source code в object code (об'єктний код). Як тоді бути з останнім?

Comment: source code - код, який може прочитати людина, і при необхідності внести туди зміни.

Comment: Не зовсім зручно.    
Як, наприкла, перекласти фразу "look into sources" у розмові з розробником / партнером / etc?    
"Дивись у код" - досить двозначно. У який код. "Вихідний"? Об'єктний? ASCII таблицю кодів? Ще щось?

Comment: "look into sources" - означає глянути на код, написаний розробником.

Comment: @OlegSobchuk, я підправив Вашу відповідь. Зокрема, правопис слова [інтерпретатор](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) та [компільована мова програмування](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) замість "компілюєма".

Comment: @обставинниковийТранспозитор а хіба `object code`не перекладають зазвичай як бінарний, чи двійковий код? Просто `об'єктний код` реально рідко зустрічається.


- Об'єктний код: ≈ 1 560
- Двійниковий: ≈ 9 130

Comment: "Код" - **набагато**, **набагато**, **набагато** ширше поняття. Відповідь невірна. Це все одно, що "apple" перекласти як "фрукт".

Answer (score -1):

Враховуючи тріаду
Вихідний код -> об’єктний код -> машинний код

то мій варіант Вихідний код

Comment: -1: те, як вживаєте ви, не є достатнім аргументом для хорошої відповіді. Спробуйте додати більш поважні джерела для обґрунтування.

Comment: Я маю на увазі, що не можна перекладати source code самостійно.

Comment: Я цілком розумію. Перегляньте, будь ласка [help], а особливо текст [How to Answer](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Там є думки стосовно того, яким має бути хороша відповідь, і чим вона відрізняється від поганої. А після прочитання не забудьте відредагувати вашу відповідь, щоб вона більше відповідала вимогам.

Comment: Думка в основі цієї відповіді правильна, хоча так, відповідь дуже лаконічна, вона має бути розрахована на людей, далеких від теми, та містити більше пояснень.

Answer (score -7):

Пропоную ідеальне рішення: **ПРАКОД**

Comment: 'код' <- 'code' <- 'codex'. українським відповідником слова 'codex' є 'правда' див: [Руська Правда Ярослава Мудрого](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russkaya_Pravda). 

'source code' таким чином можна перекласти як 'праправда' або 'першоправда', що дійсно так адже як відомо "The source code never lies"

Comment: По-моєму, не є відповіддю. Таким «пропоную варіант X» місце в коментарях або на [Словотворі](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/source-code). Тут же відповіді мають бути аргументовані (і, на мою думку, радше описові по відношенню до реального світу, аніж новаторські). P. S.: Хоча й саме питання невдало сформульоване — незрозуміло, «найкращий» з якого боку.