# Чи існує Scrum термінологія українською?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

[Scrum](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum) — дуже популярний у IT підхід управління проектами для гнучкої розробки програмного забезпечення. Я розумію, що стала російська/українська термінологія - транслітерація з англійською.

Припустимо, що я дуже хочу, хоча б і неформально, вживати зручні україномовні еквіваленти. Якими вони мають бути?

Ось список основних термінів:

- [**Плани (продукту, спинта)**](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2769/%D0%AF%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5-scrum-backlog)  - Backlog (e.g Product backlog, Sprint backlog) is an accumulation of something, especially uncompleted work or matters that need to be dealt with
- [**Графік згорання**](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2782/%D0%AF%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5-scrum-burndown-chart) - Burndown (chart)  is a graphical representation of work left to do versus time.
- [**Літучка**](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/%D0%AF%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5-scrum-daily-stand-up-meeting)  **або Щоденна нарада** - Daily (Stand-Up Meeting)  aka Daily Scrum Meeting
- [**Оцінки**](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2777/%D0%AF%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5-scrum-estimation-meeting-session)  **або Оцінна нарада**  - Estimates aka Estimation Meeting/Session
- **[Ретро(спекрива)](http://sum.in.ua/s/retrospektyvnyj) або Аналіз спринта** - (Sprint) Retro(spective) (Meeting).
- **[Демо(нстрація)](http://sum.in.ua/s/demonstracija) або Перегляд спринта** - (Sprint) Demo aka Sprint Review (Meeting)
- **[Планування](http://sum.in.ua/s/Planuvannja) або Планування спринта** - (Sprint) Planning (Meeting)

У лапках - частина яку зазвичай пропускають. Жирним - мій поточний варіант перекладу. За порадою модераторів створив окремі теми для обговорення усіх термінів крім останніх трьох, бо там переклад очевидний.

Ще важливе питання - [як краще перекладати meeting у цьому контексті](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2774/%d0%af%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%97%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-meeting-%d1%82%d0%b0-meeting-room) коли потрібно сказати повну назву?

Comment: Передбачаю, що скоро прийде людина, що скаже, що таке питання має бути розділене на декілька окремих питань (один термін у кожному). І можливо, доля правди в цьому є, хоча я не впевнений на 100%.

Comment: «Летучка» — СУМ-11 пропонує варіант [л**і**ту́чка](http://sum.in.ua/s/lituchka), хоча словник Кримського і Єфремова з ним не згоден: [л**е**ту́(ю́)чка](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=летучка&scope=rusb&dicts=1). «Аналіз спринта» — взагалі-то за словником правильно [спринт**у**](http://sum.in.ua/s/sprynt), хоча мені теж хочеться сказати _спринта_ (бо тут мається на увазі фактично не вид діяльності, а одиничний часовий проміжок).

Comment: «Оцінки» — ще є несловникове, але вживане слово [прикидка](//www.google.com/search?lr=lang_uk&tbm=bks&q=прикидка) (точніше воно [словникове](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/47594-prykydka.html), але в іншому значенні), хоча Ваш варіант, мабуть, кращий.

Comment: «Графік прогресу» для «burndown» мені не подобається — це наче протилежне за змістом, графік прогресу (в разі успіху) має йти вгору, а burndown навпаки йде донизу (і чим швидше, тим краще). Але як перекласти, на знаю. Може, щось типу «графік хвостів» (але «хвіст» — це не зовсім те, це коли ти десь схибив і зробив невчасно, а не просто робота-що-чекає-на-виконання; [отут](//www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1480800508622379/) обговорювали як коротше сказати оте робота-що-чекає, але до одного слова не скоротили).

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Попередній коментатор має рацію: це не найбільш вдале запитання на цьому сайті. Причини: (1) тут багато запитань в одному, які треба **розділяти**; інакше, як ви вибиратимете між дописами, які надають відповіді на частини ABD, BFG та ACXYZ? (2) **«і т.і.»** — це взагалі не запитання, на «і т.і.» ніхто і ніколи не відповість; (3) кожен термін варто пояснювати своїми словами і надавати **контекст**; перегляньте інші високорейтингові запитання за тегом [tag:переклад], там є гарні зразки.

Comment: З іншого боку, ви можете запитувати не про переклад конкретних слів, а про друковані чи онлайн-матеріали стосовно IT-термінології. Таке запитання також мало б право на існування.

Comment: Замість прогрес ліпше вжити перебіг або поступ. Але, зважаючи на коментар Sasha вище, можна скористатися словосполученням графік залишків, тобто йде мова про залишки роботи, яку ще не виконали.

Comment: @АндрійБандура, або «рештків»/«остачі».

Comment: Я бачив як людина питала переклад [тенісних термінів](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/929/what-are-the-common-tennis-terms-in-ukrainian) і вирішив, що це легітимне питання тут.  Судячи з коментарів, цей сайт працює як інтелектуальний словник. Кожна фраза має бути окремим питанням. Це незручно, багатослівно та клопітно. Це ділення буде штучним, бо людина зазвичай шукає переклад усіх термінів разом, а не по черзі. Якщо ви наполягаєте, то можу створити 7 окремих питань

Comment: @finesoul пан bytebuster і там зауважував, що питання треба виправити: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/929/what-are-the-common-tennis-terms-in-ukrainian#comment2458_929
Якщо коротко, то: більше дослідження, менше питань в одному пості.

Comment: @finesoul, ні, цей сайт не словник, а учасник мережі сайтів Q&A. Переклади — це велика тема для сайтів мережі, присвячених мовам. Але не єдина. Основою є те, що ми маємо дотримуватися Q&A формату. Так, 7 окремих запитань краще, ніж одне; тільки не забудьте, що хороші запитання містять контекст і власну спробу відповісти. А також пояснення, чим са́ме авторська відповідь не подобається авторові. Ось хороші приклади: [один](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/33/), [два](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/83/), [три](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/579/)

Comment: Як багато це часу займає. [Backlog](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2769/%d0%af%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%97%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%8e-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5-scrum-backlog) переніс у окреме питання. Решту можливо зроблю згодом.

Comment: Мені все подобається. А хто може це на Wikipedia перенести? Бо сторінка там убога на цю тему

Answer (score 3):

#### «Посібник зі Скраму»

Є [«Посібник зі Скраму. Повний навчальний посібник зі Скраму: правила гри» від липня 2016](http://scrumguides.org/docs/scrumguide/v2016/2016-Scrum-Guide-Ukrainian.pdf) (громадський переклад офіційного [«The Scrum Guide. The Definitive Guide to Scrum: The Rules of the Game»](http://scrumguides.org/download.html), автори оригіналу Кен Швабер і Джефф Сазерленд, перекладач Дмитро Бібіков та інші із SoftServe; також доступний [переклад першої версії від 2011](http://www.scrumguides.org/docs/scrumguide/v1/Scrum-Guide-UA.pdf) з трішки іншими перекладами термінів).

Там перекладають так:

- «Product Backlog» → «Беклог Продукту» (ст. 13; але в першій версії: «Журнал Продукту» (ст. 13)).
- «Sprint Backlog» → «Беклог Спринту» (ст. 14; але в першій версії: «Журнал Спринту» (ст. 15)).
- «Burn-down» → «графік типу „скільки залишилось“» (ст. 14).
  <sub>Також «burn-up» → «графік типу „скільки зроблено“», «cumulative flow» → «кумулятивна діаграма» (ст. 14).</sub>
- «Daily Scrum» → «Щоденний Скрам» (ст. 11).
- «Estimate» → «оцінка обсягів роботи» (ст. 13, ст. 14), «оцінка очікуваних затрат часу», «оцінка об'єму роботи», «оцінка» (ст. 14).
- «Sprint Retrospective» → «Ретроспектива Спринту» (ст. 12).
- «Sprint Review» → «Огляд Спринту» (ст. 11).
- «Sprint Planning» → «Планування Спринту» (ст. 9).

#### «Scrum. Навчись робити вдвічі більше за менший час»

Є [переклад книги Джеффа Сазерленда «Scrum. Навчись робити вдвічі більше за менший час» 2016 року видавництва «Клуб сімейного дозвілля»](//books.google.com/books?id=cKnnDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT0).

Там перекладають так:

- «беклог продукту»;
- «беклог спринту»;
- «планування спринту»;
- «діаграма згоряння завдань»;
- «щоденний стендап»;
- «огляд, або демонстрація спринту»;
- «ретроспектива спринту».

Ще деякі вислови з цього перекладу (здається, недоступні через онлайн-версію на Google Books, але засвідчені покупцем паперової версії) є [тут](//dou.ua/forums/topic/22181/?utm_campaign=comment#1215447).

#### Особисті ідеї

- «Burndown chart» — «графік незробленого/невиконаного/незавершеного/недоробок/недопрацювань» (також «… залишків/решток» [per Андрій Бандура](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/2767#comment4964_2767)).

#### Інші обговорення

- [На форумі linux.org.ua](//linux.org.ua/index.php?topic=891).

Answer (score 1):

Про переклад всіх термінів не скажу, але в проекті яким я займаюсь, **backlog** я переклав як **комора**.

[image]

Гадаю, що **daily meeting** можна перекласти як **щодень**. Це має перевагу перед летучкою в тому, що *летучка* може бути по необхідності, а *щодень* він явно запланований щодня.