# Як українською буде Scrum Backlog?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

[Scrum](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum) — дуже популярний у IT підхід управління проектами для гнучкої розробки програмного забезпечення. Наразі українська термінологія - транслітерація з англійської (іноді через російську).

Backlog перекладають як [беклог](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum), Sprint Backlog - беклог спринта, Product Backlog (aka Backlog) - беклог продукту (aka беклог).

Сутність терміну беклог дуже гарно пояснює гугл-перекладач

> Backlog is an accumulation of something, especially uncompleted work
>   or matters that need to be dealt with

Product backlog є списком великих і малих змін, які треба зробити у продукті. Sprint backlog є списком того, що має бути реалізовано протягом спринта. Коли починається/планується новий спринт, Sprint Backlog формується з найпріоритетніших на поточний момент елементів Product backlog.

Дуже широко вживається словосполучення кинути/покласти/перекинути/створити/викинути історію до/у/в/з беклог(-у)(-зі).

Припустимо, що я дуже хочу, хоча б і неформально, вживати зручні україномовні еквіваленти. Як краще перекласти Backlog? Ну і відповідно, як перекласти Sprint Backlog та Product backlog?

Наразі найкраще, що я маю - плани, плани спринта, плани продукту. Але "кинь історію у плани" трохи ріже вухо.  Може є кращій переклад?

Comment: трохи відредаґував. якщо маєте щось проти редактури - не мовчіть.

Comment: @P. Vovk, дякую за допомогу. Я знаю, що неуважний. Помилки варто виправляти.

Comment: Ось тут [питання про офіційну Scrum-термінологію українською](/q/2767).

Answer (score 1):

Ідеї:

- **Завдання** чи **задачі**. Суто інтуїтивна споба. Наприклад, «завдання спринту» або «задачі на спринт» («кинути до задач», «викинути із задач»).

  Чим погано: *завдання* і *задачі* асоціюються з англійським *tasks*; у термінології scrum'у *user story* (*історія* або *[розповідь користувача](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%8C_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0)*) і *task* — не одне й те саме; у backlog ідуть зазвичай (хоча не обов'язково) розповіді користувача, а не *task'и*.

  Чому можна використати попри це: ніхто не зобов'язує передавати термінологію один до одного; теоретично *завдання*/*задача* може бути узагальнюючим терміном і для *user story*, і для *task*.
- **Журнал замовлень**.

  Спроби обґрунтування:

  - є в словнику Мейнаровича і Кратка як [переклад для *backlog*](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=backlog&dicts=2&main_only=on);
  - трішки схожий варіант використовується в російській Вікіпедії — *[журнал пожеланий](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum#.D0.96.D1.83.D1.80.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BB_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B9_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B5.D0.BA.D1.82.D0.B0)* (дослівно «журнал побажань»);
  - такий варіант перекладу [розглядали і на форумі linux.org.ua](//linux.org.ua/index.php?topic=891.msg42146#msg42146) (раніше він був у їхньому словнику, що зараз недоступний).

  Підваріант: **замовлення** («кинути до замовлень», «викинути із замовлень»).
- Прикметникові варіанти, навіяні [іншими перекладами *backlog* на E2U](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=backlog&dicts=all&filter_lines=on): **незроблені**, **невиконані**, **незавершені** (наприклад, «кинути до „незроблених“») — більше схоже на місцевий сленґ конкретної організації, але теоретично використання можливе.

Comment: У баклозі історії різних розмірів: від епічних до дріб'язку. Там десь 4 градації.  Крім того  термін **задача\завдання\мета** спринта вже існує окремо. **Журнал** спринта і продукту - можливо, хоча і не впевнений, що це краще ніж плани. **Замовлення** спринта і продукту - дуже спантеличує.

Comment: чому комора не підходить?

Comment: @Yola, нічого не маю проти, просто навів варіанти, що прийшли на думку мені. (Хоча, якщо чесно, мені асоціація з «коморою» не дуже інтуїтивно зрозуміла, але не кажу, що вона погана, тим більше, що я ніколи не працював за Scrum'ом, тож моє уявлення про нього чисто теоретичне.) P.S.: Буде добре, якщо Ви скопіюєте [ту Вашу відповідь](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2768) сюди.

Comment: @Sasha, модератори просили **не** писати відповіді [у тему про основну термінологію скраму](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2768), бо складно буде дати відразу  найкращу відповідь на всі 7 запитань. Я постараюсь нарізати усі шматочки протягом тижня. Це - перший шматочок.

Comment: @Yola, [комора](http://sum.in.ua/s/komora) - це приміщення.

Comment: @finesoul, модератор же мені і [запропонував](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2771) (не знаю, чи видно Вам той діалог, чи ні, якщо ні, то [ось](//i.stack.imgur.com/AMSrm.png)) перенести відповідь туди.

Comment: @finesoul, (про комору) просто одне із [значень](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/backlog#Noun) слова _backlog_ — «запас/припас/заділ/ресурси/фонд» (тому й «комора»). Хоча саме із невиконаною роботою (а не із будматеріалами чи ще чимось) мені «комора» (а також «запас/припас/ресурси/…») теж мало асоціюється.

Comment: @finesoul це метафора. Наприклад, ми знаємо. що стрижень це щось тверде й пряме, але ж ми ще можемо сказати "У нього є внутрішній стрижень", маючи на увазі психологічний стрижень. Наразі у *комори* я бачу лише один недолік як замінника цього терміну - вона часто невпорядкована, *беклог* - впорядкований.

Comment: @finesoul хоча є ж термін *backlog triage*, це якраз воно і є сортування комори, тобто ви посуртували комору і тепер там вже лежать завданняя в більш сортованому порядку. Тому я все ще пропоную термін *комора*.

Comment: @Sasha, [тут](http://www.scrumguides.org/docs/scrumguide/v1/Scrum-Guide-UA.pdf#zoom=100) беклог називають саме журналом.

Comment: @finesoul, хм, цікаво. А в [2-й версії (від 2016)](http://www.scrumguides.org/docs/scrumguide/v2016/2016-Scrum-Guide-Ukrainian.pdf), як я [вже казав](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2772), таки «беклог». Цікаво, чому вони відмовилися від слова «журнал».

Answer (score 1):

В сучасному українському діловодстві журнали називають книгами, наприклад:

- книга обліку доходів і витрат
- книга обліку руху трудових книжок
- книга відгуків та пропозицій

Тож, доповнюючи ідеї @Sasha, пропоную варіант:

- книга завданнь

Comment: [Книга](http://sum.in.ua/s/knygha) - це щось статичне. Книга обліку заповнюється зверху вниз протягом її існування. Порядок, пріоритет і склад беклогу постійно змінюється. "Створити історію у книзі" заплутає кого завгодно.

Comment: @finesoul, з іншого боку, художня книга часто складається з розповідей. Тож «додати розповідь до книги» може бути цікавою алегорією. Крім того, хто сказав, що нові записи додаються лише знизу, це особливість лмше паперового варіанту.

Comment: @finesoul, журнал (log) в його первісному значенні також має ознаки статичності