# Як українською краще перекласти meeting та meeting room?

Tags: переклад, from-english

У [скрамі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum) є декілька регулярних і частих робочих зустрічей. Вони заплановані на роки вперед, але відбуваються у досить неформальній обстановці. Англійською це усе називається meeting. Відбуваються вони усі у meeting room.

Як зручно і правильно назвати такі зустрічі українською?
Відповідно, як назвати місце де вони відбуваються?

Найкраще, як на мене, підходить [нарада](http://sum.in.ua/s/narada) і кімната для нарад. Плюс - є скорочена назва - нарадова (як російською - переговорка), мінус - якось воно сприймається занадто пафосно, формально і офіційно.

Трохи контексту (конкретні назви нарад розглянемо пізніше окремо):

- Ретро нарада або Нарада з аналізу спринта - Sprint Retrospective
  Meeting.
- Демо нарада або  Нарада з огляду спринта - Sprint Demo aka Sprint
  Review Meeting
- Нарада з планування спринта - Sprint Planning Meeting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Meeting

Важко сказати, що краще підходить. Це частково суб'єктивно. Можу сказати, що я думаю про різні синоніми.

«**Нарада**» найточніше з відомих мені слів передає суть явища. Якщо воно не подобається Вам формальністю, то, звісно, Ваше право вживати інші. Але формально воно підходить.

«**[Зустріч](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=38463&page=1200)**» теж цілком підходить. Одне зі значень цього слова за «Словником української мови» в 20 томах: «тимчасове спільне перебування де-небудь для обговорення яких-небудь питань, для бесіди, наради і т. ін.». Але це слово менш точне (ширше), ніж «нарада».

«**[Рада](http://sum.in.ua/s/rada)**» — формально підходить. Але, на мою думку, на практиці буде **дуже незручним** через наявність у цього слова інших значень, що важко відсікти контекстом і які при цьому приходять до думок раніше за потрібне.

«*[Збори](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=34488&page=1099)*» і «*[зібрання](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=36199&page=1143)*», на мою думку, загалом, **не підходять**. Тому що вони натякають на зібрання більшої кількості людей, ніж це відбувається під час багатьох скрам-зустрічей. Підприємтво в загальному випадку може розробляти декілька *продуктів* (кожен з яких може мати своїх *власника продукту* і інших *зацікавлених осіб*); один *продукт* в загальному випадку може розроблятися декількома *командами* (кожна з яких може мати свого *скрам-мастера*); одна *команда* складається з малої кількості *розробників* (зазвичай приблизно п'ять). У більшості ж передбачених Скрамом зустрічей (Daily, Sprint Retrospective) бере участь лише *одна команда* і її *скрам-мастер*, у деяких — ще *власник* відповідного *продукту* (Sprint Planning, Sprint Review) або й навіть інші *зацікавлені сторони*, але знов таки лише цього *продукту* (Sprint Review); зустріч відразу *декількох команд*, що працюють над *одним продуктом*, зазвичай проводять нечасто (я так розумію, це доречно здебільшого для Sprint Review і частково Sprint Planning; часто замість зібрання декількох команд обирають Scrum of Scrums — зустріч представників команд); зустріч осіб (розробників, власників продуктів тощо), що стосуються різних продуків — майже ніколи (принаймні, це, здається, вже щось поза Скрамом). Таким чином, якщо на підприємстві є декілька команд (а то й навіть декілька продуктів) — то зовсім не кожну зустріч можна назвати зборами; хоча **в певних випадках** (якщо на підприємстві всього одна команда або якщо на конкретній зустрічі присутня більша за звичну кількість осіб) використання цих слів **можливе**.

«*[Засідання](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=32325&page=1044)*» — в загальному випадку **не підходить**, бо деякі типи зустрічей (Daily) часто спеціально проводять навстоячки. І навіть якщо учасники зустрічі сидять, використання цього терміну мені видається небажаним, бо воно не відповідає духу Скраму, де зустрічі мають проводитися оперативно, з жорсткими обмеженнями часу. Хоча формально використання терміну **можливе**.

«*[Мітинг](http://sum.in.ua/s/mityngh)*» **однозначно не підходить**, бо поки що не має в українській мові значення «звичайна нарада/зустріч» (натомість — «масові збори з приводу обговорення якихось злободенних питань, переважно політичних»).

«*[Літучка](http://sum.in.ua/s/lituchka)*» (також [«*летучка*» і «*летючка*»](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=rusb&dicts=1)), «*[оперативка](http://sum.in.ua/s/operatyvka)*», «*п'ятнадцятихвилинка*» (аналогічно до «[п'ятихвилинка](http://sum.in.ua/s/p.jatykhvylynka)») — **лише для Daily** (чи Daily поза цим питанням?).

«*Колоквіум*», «*консиліум*», «*побачення*», «*рандеву*», «*раут*» — **зовсім не те**.

«*Сходини*» — мабуть, теж не дуже (діалектично може означати будь-яку зустріч, але в нормативному значенні, це, здається, передбачає збори, причому з невиробничими підставами).

#### Meeting room

Мені подобається ідея скоротити назву до одного слова, але слів «нарадова»/«нарадна» я в жодному словнику не знайшов, лише «[переговорну](http://sum.in.ua/s/pereghovornyj)». Звісно, можна казати в лоба: «кімната/зал для нарад/зустрічей/переговорів» — але не хочеться. На практиці, мені здається, це може бути вирішене використанням назв, що залежать не лише від її призначення в процесі Скраму, а й, наприклад, від її повного чи побічного призначення (наприклад, «конференц-зал», «співбесідна» тощо) чи то навіть від її фактичних характеристик («біля шефа», «зі скляним столом / „скляна“», «що з проектором»).

Comment: > слів «нарадова»/«нарадна» я в жодному словнику не знайшов

А як щодо "нарадча кімната"?

Comment: @hutorny, точно! [_нара́дчий_, _ра́дний_](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=нарадчий&scope=ukr&dicts=5). є й інші джерела ([1](//books.google.com/books?id=fn0pAQAAIAAJ&q=нарадча), [2](//books.google.com/books?id=wPYnAQAAIAAJ&q=нарадча), [3](//books.google.com/books?id=FJNFAQAAIAAJ&q=нарадча), [4](//books.google.com/books?id=w50MAQAAIAAJ&q=нарадча), [5](//books.google.com/books?id=zYEkAQAAIAAJ&q=нарадча), [6](//books.google.com/books?id=WhwVAQAAIAAJ&q=нарадча)).