# Як українською буде Scrum Estimation Meeting/Session?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

[Scrum](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum) — дуже популярний у IT підхід управління проектами для гнучкої розробки програмного забезпечення. Наразі українська термінологія - транслітерація з англійської (іноді через російську).

Перед плануванням спринта команда збирається на нараді, щоб оцінити складність задач з найвищим пріоритетом та, коли необхідно, розбити дуже великі задачі на менші, які потенційно можуть бути зроблені протягом спринта. Таких зустрічей може бути декілька, і вони не завжди безпосередньо пов'язані з плануванням спринта. Головна їх риса - команда оцінює задачі з планів (беклогу) продукту, їх складність.

Англійською це називається Estimation Session або Estimation Meeting. Якщо треба коротку і зручну версію - Estimates. Українською мабуть буде **оцінна нарада** та **оцінки**.

Можливо є якісь кращі варіанти перекладу.

Контекст:

- Я зайнятий, у нас зараз оцінки.
- Ходімо оцінювати.
- Завтра о другій оцінна нарада. (Трохи ріже вухо)
- Завтра о другій оцінки.
- Це ми оцінимо завтра на оцінках. (Тавтологія)
- Це ми оцінимо завтра на оцінній нараді. (Трохи краще)

Comment: Чи є «Estimation Meeting/Session» частиною Scrum? Мені здається, це вже одна з над-Scrum-ових надбудов (Scrum визначає необхідний мінімум, без якого робочий процес не можна вважати таким, що відбувається за Scrum; але він не забороняє додатково вточнювати процес, додаючи своїх елементів, якщо при цьому не прибирати необхідні; деякі з додаткових елементів стають поширеними практиками; мені, здається, окремий Estimation Meeting/Session — це один з таких (поширене, але не обов'язкове доповнення до Scrum)). Чи воно десь описане, як частина Scrum?

Comment: @Sasha, це - частина [Backlog Refinement/Grooming](https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/backlog-grooming/) яку дуже часто роблять окремою нарадою щоб значно спростити планування.

Comment: Ясно. (Іншими словами — це Backlog Refinement Meeting ([1](//www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/product-backlog-refinement-grooming), [2](http://scrumtrainingseries.com/BacklogRefinementMeeting/BacklogRefinementMeeting.htm), [3](//www.scrum.org/forum/scrum-forum/6601/backlog-refinement-meeting)). Формально Scrum не предписує, що це має бути окремою нарадою, але каже, що це має бути зробленим, причому займаючи не більше 10% потужності команди — і часто зручно робити це окремою нарадою (де часто присутня не вся команда; щоб підготувати backlog до Sprint Planning; а на Sprint Planning — вся).)

Comment: У тексті за вашим посиланням немає слова *estimation*. Там є *grooming* і його нові назви, бо не всім подобається така назва.

Comment: @Yola,  "* assigning estimates to stories which have yet to receive one
* correcting estimates in light of newly discovered information"

Comment: так, але звідки взявся термін *estimation meeting?*

Comment: Чи не могли б ви дати відповідь на моє запитання? Бо наразі у мене склалось враження, що це не термін зі Scrum'у і відповідно запитання поставлено некоректно.

Answer (score 1):

> [Scrum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scrum) Etymology From scrummage, from scrimmage (source: The
>   Heritage Illustrated Dictionary of the English Language).

[Тут](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Team_Practices_Group/Scrum_Estimation_Meeting) можна знайти слово синонім до scrum. Де вказують

> Team Practices Group/Scrum Estimation Meeting

Тобто по суті своїй Scrum Estimation Meeting перекладається як, якщо враховувати слово синонім, **Зустріч Групової Оцінки**.

Але можна піти глибше.

> [Scrimmage](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scrimmage#English) A corruption of skirmish.
>
> scrimmage (plural scrimmages)
>
> A rough fight.
>
> (US) In some team sports, especially soccer, a practice game which
>   does not count on a team's record.
>
> In American football or Canadian football, a play that begins with a snap from the center while
>   opposing teams are on either side of a line of scrimmage.

Тобто бійка, [**сутичка**](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0), [**зіткнення**](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F), але для даного випадку ближче буде [**суперечка**](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0).

В результаті вище зазначеного можна перекласти як: зустріч для оцінювання через суперечку, бійку або ж:

**Scrum Estimation Meeting** - **Зустріч Суперечкового Оцінювання**.

Тепер можна, для підтвердження нашої теорії, перейти до словника, де слово **scrum** використане в інших випадках з вище зазначеним значенням.

> [scrum](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scrum)
>
> in the sport of rugby, a group of attacking players from each team who
>   come together with their heads down and arms joined, and push against
>   each other, trying to take control of the ball
>
> a situation in which a group of people push each other to get to a
>   place or obtain something

Comment: Це жахливий переклад. Слово "scrum" має різні значення. Ви починаєте об'єднувати переклад  одного значення слова із іншим через те, що [значення слова зі сфери ІТ, пов'язане зі значення слова із регбі на основі походження](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(software_development)#History) (що ви, до речі не написали, а зробили висновок на основі власних суджень).

Comment: Звичайно, носії англійської, коли хтось говорить про скрам в ІТ, можуть асоціювати це слово значенням із регбі, проте це зв'язок адекватно *не можна* відобразити в українській без пошкодження перекладу слова в контексті ІТ сфери. Це стандартний tradeoff про який знає будь-який перекладач: якщо перекладати значення слова для якогось контексту часто потрібно відрубати можливі забарвлення і зв'язки із іншими слова із оригінальної мови, інакше ризикуєш зробити неякійсний переклад значення слова як мінімум, у вашому випадку зробити жаливу мовну мішанину, яка погано відображає оригінальне значення.

Comment: Особисто я прихильник відсутності перекладу термінів і понять при перекладі.

Comment: @improbable "Особисто я прихильник відсутності перекладу термінів і понять при перекладі.". Якщо ви не можете або ж не хочете описати англійське слово українською мовою, то це означає, що ви не перекладаєте слово. Тобто не намагаєтеся виконати основну функцію перекладу: донести значення іноземного слова.

Comment: @improbable "Слово "scrum" має різні значення." Не зовсім згоден. Це слово має один корінь, який має своє певне значення. В залежності від змісту використання слово впливає на загальне значення словосполучення або ж речення. Чи ви можете довести, що scrum має різні корені у випадках для реґбі та для ІТ?

Comment: @improbable "а зробили висновок на основі власних суджень" все роблять на основі власних суджень. Група людей створює тлумачні словники на основі власних суджень, зроблених на основі зібраних даних. Питання не в тому чи вони власні чи ні, а в тому як довести, що ці судження правильні чи не правильні? Ви можете навести декілька прикладів, де думка суперечить описаній мною? Щоб можна було якось або довести, що я не правий, або ж довести, що моя точка зору правильна.

Comment: @improbable Про tradeoff не зрозумів. Не знайомий з цим словом.