# Як українською буде Scrum Daily Stand-Up Meeting?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

[Scrum](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum) — дуже популярний у IT підхід управління проектами для гнучкої розробки програмного забезпечення. Я розумію, що стала російська/українська термінологія - транслітерація з англійською

Ця зустріч відбувається кожен день протягом спринта. Є «пульсом» ходу спринта. Їй властиві наступні обмеження:

- починається точно вчасно;
- триває не більш ніж 15 хвилин;
- проводиться в одному і стоячи.

Wiki перекладає назву як **[Щоденна](http://sum.in.ua/s/shhodennyj) нарада**. Мені переклад подобається, але він не акцентує уваги на тому, що зустріч проводиться швидко і стоячи.

На скорочену назву краще претендує [**Літучка**](http://sum.in.ua/s/lituchka), але переклад не пов'язаний граматично з повним.

Чи є якась краща пара?

Контекст:

- Не спізнися на літучку
- Я не встигну на літучку
- Літучки сьогодні не буде.
- Після літучки обговоримо це докладніше
- Літучка! (заклик, що час вже зібратися і починати)

Comment: Пробачте, яка транслітерація з англійською Scrum Daily Stand-Up Meeting? Я використав ua.translit.cc та отримав 'Сцрум Даіли Станд-Уп Меетінґ' Виглядає дуже неправильно. Чи є кращий сайт для транслітерації?

Comment: @Arthur Tarasov, англійською це кажуть так  - `Скрам Дейлі Стендап Мітінг` або просто - `Дейлі`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вже писав у [цій відповіді](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2775), що мені прийшли до думки такі варіанти:

- «**[Літу́чка](http://sum.in.ua/s/lituchka)**» (за версією «Словника української мови»; або ж [«**лету́чка**» чи «**летю́чка**»](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=rusb&dicts=1) — за версією «Російсько-українського словника» А. Кримського і С. Єфремова).

  Про цей варіант Ви кажете, що він «не пов'язаний граматично з повним» — але я не розумію, що це означає. «Scrum Daily Stand-Up Meeting» можна перекласти як «*щоденна скрам-літучка*». Якщо не подобається відсутність слова «нарада», то нагадаю, що «літучка» є скороченням від «літуча/летюча нарада» (приклади: [1](http://studopedia.com.ua/1_28310_leksikologIya-yak-rozdIl-movoznavstva.html), [2](//books.google.com/books?id=-7PcDAAAQBAJ&q=%22%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%22), [3](//books.google.com/books?id=DvzWAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%22)).
- [«**Операти́вка**» (або «**операти́вна нара́да**»)](http://sum.in.ua/s/operatyvka).
- «**П'ятнадцятихвилинка**» (аналогічно до «[п'ятихвилинки](http://sum.in.ua/s/p.jatykhvylynka)»).

Також можу запропонувати такі розмовні варіанти:

- «*Нара́д**к**а*» (зменшувальне від «нарада»).
- «*Стоя́чка*» (якщо справді стоячки).
- «*Щоде́нка*».

Answer (score 3):

Літучка не підходить, бо це будь-яка швидка (на літу) нарада. Це слово не відображає щоденності наради. Я пропоную використовувати **щодень**.

- Ходімо на *щодень*.
- Щось цікаве було на *щодні*?

Якщо описаних вище мінусів літучки недостатньо, то дам ще один. *Літучка - це така нарада, на якій в одно вухо влітає, а з іншого вилітає.*