# Як українською буде Scrum Burndown Chart?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

[Scrum](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum) — дуже популярний у IT підхід управління проектами для гнучкої розробки програмного забезпечення. Наразі українська термінологія - транслітерація з англійської (іноді через російську).

Burndown chart — показує, скільки вже виконано і скільки ще залишається зробити.
[image: Burndown chart for 2 weeks sprint]

По горизонталі відзначаємо дні — це двотижневий спринт, 10 робочих днів. По вертикалі story points незакритих історій з планів спринта. Якщо б ми з вами були роботами, а завдання маленькими і розбитими на шматочки, то ми йшли б по червоною лінією — це лінія ідеального Burn Down Charts. В реальності ми йдемо десь синьою лінією.

Як краще перекласти цю назву?

Я називаю це **графіком прогресу**. Можливо варто називати дослівно **графіком згорання**

Comment: Не хочу видатись занудою, але Burndown Chart не є специфічним виключно для Scrum а використовується в Agile методології 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burn_down_chart
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469358/what-is-the-difference-between-scrum-and-agile-development

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Варіанти, що хоч десь використовуються/застосовуються <sub>(з указанням де саме і сортуваннями за першими літерами після слова «графік»/«діаграма»/«схема»; це wiki-відповідь, її можна розширювати іншим людям)</sub>:

- «**діаграма згоряння завдань**», «**діаграма згоряння завдань**»  <sub>//[Джефф Сазерленд «Scrum. Навчись робити вдвічі більше за менший час» (2016, Харків, «Клуб сімейного дозвілля»)](//books.google.com/books?id=cKnnDQAAQBAJ&q=%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F);</sub>
- «burndown» → «**поступ**» <sub>//[Microsoft Terminology Collection](//www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/Search?searchTerm=burndown&langID=Ukrainian&productid=All+Products);</sub>
- «**графік типу „скільки залишилось“**» <sub>//[Кен Швабер і Джефф Сазерленд «Посібник зі Скраму. Повний навчальний посібник зі Скраму: правила гри» (липень 2016)](http://scrumguides.org/docs/scrumguide/v2016/2016-Scrum-Guide-Ukrainian.pdf), ст. 14;</sub>
- «burndown» → «**хід виконання**» <sub>//[Microsoft Project 2013, 2016, 2017-QR2](//www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/Search?searchTerm=burndown&langID=Ukrainian&productid=All+Products).</sub>

Comment: Microsoft тут на висоті.

Answer (score 1):

Спеціально створив окрему відповідь, щоби відділити власні ідеї від того, що десь застосовується:

- графік залишків;
- графік невиконаного;
- графік недоробок;
- графік недопрацювань;
- графік незавершеного;
- графік незробленого;
- графік решток.